# How to use Open Shot video API with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been looking at the [LibOpenShot](https://github.com/OpenShot/libopenshot) for some video creation using Rails.

The repository states that they have bindings for Ruby, but I cannot find any reference to ruby, e.g. a Gem

Does anyone know how to use OpenShot with Ruby?

Comment: You may start from the https://www.openshot.org/cloud-api/ page.

Comment: I have checked that and I can see how it would work from a remote cloud api, but I thought there was also a local library for doing local processing

Comment: They provide a downloadble editor.

Comment: Same, I'm looking for the python bindings. I might shop around for another video-editing library. This is a bad sign that there's so little documentation